# Where should I close the sql.DB?

Tags: go

According to the [godoc](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Close):

> It is rare to Close a DB, as the DB handle is meant to be long-lived
> and shared between many goroutines.

Is there any use cases of this method except calling it `defer db.Close()` inside the `main` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never close databases. Deferring it in main likely won't hurt... but it won't help anything either. The end of main is the end of the program and if main ends, the OS does the cleaning.

---

*Edit:*

> So why we need it in public API of the database/sql package?

Closing a DB is useful if you don't plan to use the database again. It does all the cleanup that would be done at program termination but allows the program to continue to run.

Comment: So why we need it in public API of the `database/sql` package?

Comment: @tarrsalah - If you don't have the requirement of a long-lived connection to the DB then you can close it.  Otherwise it will get cleaned up upon exit of main.  What's more important is that your queries and transactions are closed appropriately so you don't unnecessarily leak connections.

Comment: The other thing to remember is that the documentation states that `sql.DB.Open` doesn't _actually_ have to open a connection. It may simply do some housekeeping and prepare to connect.. its driver specific. That's why `sql.DB.Ping` exists.. to check if you have actually connected.